# Selecting a Capacitor for an application

Tags: capacitor

I have been designing circuits recently,and the way I come to think of a resistor is that it limits the current and I can do the math to get the right value.

With a Capacitor I am aware that it passes AC Through and blocks DC, and it can also store energy, and output it as a voltage. But what is a good way to come to think of a capacitor when doing circuit designs?

Comment: As a momentary short circuit.

Comment: specify the application. CApacitors have different purposes...

Comment: The only 'one way' would be the mathematical model as given by Alfred, but even that must sometimes be corrected for the non-ideal properties of real capacitors. IMO you would be better of by studying the standard applications of capacitors, for instance as buffer in power supplies, as DC-block / AC-pass in coupling AC amplifier stages, and as 'frequency-dependent resistor' in simple filters.

Answer (score 1):

> But what is a good way to come to think of a capacitor when doing
>   circuit designs?

It is good to think of it as precisely what it (ideally) is:  a two-terminal circuit element where the current through is proportional to the time rate of change of the voltage across:

$$i_C = C \dfrac{dv_C}{dt}$$